# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Unable to Create New Custom Entity - The dependent component Attribute does not exist

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I received this error the other day when trying to create a new entity in CRM.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: There should be at least one metadata entity returned. Count: 0Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>There should be at least one metadata entity returned. Count: 0</Message>
  <Timestamp>2016-04-27T20:13:29.801472Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

---

```
  <Message>The dependent component Attribute (Id=[AttributeId]) does not exist.  Failure trying to associate it with RelationshipExtraCondition (Id=[RelationshipExtraConditionId]) as a dependency. Missing dependency lookup type = PrimaryKeyLookup.</Message>
```

After racking the internet for users with similar issues, I still haven't been able to find a resolution. For a handful of users, the system had a form or template that was referencing a value that no longer existed and removing that from the form or re-creating resolved the issue.

My understanding is that I wouldn't have been able to delete a field from CRM if it was still referenced somewhere in the application for CRM 2011 and up. The message indicates that the referenced Attribute doesn't exist but when I query the [MetadataSchema].[Attribute] table it returns a result referencing 'RegardingObjectTypeCode'. It seems like a new Guid is generated for the RelationshipExtraCondition every time I try to create the custom entity.

I checked the application event logs on the server and there's no record that logs this.

Any suggestions how I can troubleshoot this issue more?

Environment: CRM 2011 On Premise

Comment: How are you trying to create the entity?  Import?  Regular creation through the UI? Programmatically?

Comment: I tried through the UI and then programmatically but same error when trying both ways. There was a suggestion that this was tied to an inconsistency in Active Directory but I don't see how that would affect it if nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm having this issue on CRM 2013 on-prem

Comment: I don't know if this will work for you or but I resolved mine by restarting the VM running my CRM instance.

Comment: Thank you. My issue was resolved after restarting the servers a few times. I haven't been able to find the actual cause of the issue.